# Jquery: What is the best way to select the newly added DOM node?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, append, selector

I have an external template file with a  structure that is dynamically added to a table when a button is clicked. When the new table line is added this way, I need to call a callback on this newly added piece of code.

I would like to know, what is the best way to select this new  code. It has an ID, so it won't be a problem to write some other selector, but I was wondering if there is an easier and fast way how to select it.

Here is the piece of code:

```
$rightSpot.append(app.renderTemplate('temp/product', tplData ));
```

**EDIT:** This works for me, but maybe there is a better way:

```
$newProduct = $rightSpot.find('tr').last().find('textarea');
```

Comment: You probably mean "select the newly added DOM node".

Comment: what template library are you using?

Comment: You can edit the title of the question as well, to better reflect the common terminology.

Answer (score 0):

I would consider using react.js. The advantage of using react is that it works with a virtual DOM so you will not be reliant of the physical DOM to render before your callback is available.

http://facebook.github.io/react/

Comment: Sounds great, but can't switch to react.js as I am not the one who decides about it. :/

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it is the best way but you could do something like this -

```js
$("#giveitafriend").click(function() {
  $("#ab").append($("<span>")
    .text("I'm here too!")
    .css("color", "red")
  );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="ab">
  <span>On My  Own</span>
</div>
<button id="giveitafriend">Give it a Friend</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your renderTemplate function returns HTML element, may be you can access the new element as follows

```
var newElement = app.renderTemplate('temp/product', tplData ); 
$rightSpot.append(newElement);
console.log($(newElement).attr('id'));
```

Comment: You'd probably want `$(newElement).attr('id')` if `app.renderTemplate` is returning HTML rather than a jQuery object.

Comment: Thanks @JohnC for spotting typo